# Make $ .ajax consider Response code 40x as success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jQuery executes the function "success" if the HTTP status code is in the range of 200 and 299 or is equal to 304.
However, for example, for the code 401 I need jQuery considers that the Ajax call is successful, and it evaluates the response as JSON and executes the function "success".

The problem is that this behavior is hard-coded in the method "done":

```
// Determine if successful
isSuccess = status> = 200 && status <300 || === status 304;
```

I do not really see how to do that.

EDIT:

This is what I have for the moment:

```
var options = {
    url: '',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    success: function(response, status){},
    error: function(res, status, error){
        notify("Une erreur s'est produite !", "danger");
    },
    complete: function(res, status){}
};
$.extend(options, opts);
var dataString = '';
$.each(options.data, function(key, value){
    dataString += ((dataString.length > 0) ? '&' : '') + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value)
});
$.ajax({
    url: site_url + options.url,
    type: options.type,
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    statusCode: {
        401: function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                location.reload();
            }, 2000);
        }
    },
    success: function(response, status){
        if (response.response.result.status == 'ok'){
            options.success(response, status);
        } else {
            if ('message' in response.response.result){
                notify(response.response.result.message, "danger");
            } else if (response.response.errors.length > 0) {
                notify(response.response.errors[0], "danger");
            }

        }
    },
    error: options.error,
    complete: options.complete
});
```

I want the answer to be parsed according to the dataType provided (which is only for the "success" method), and, in the case of a code 401, processing is the same as for the other responses containing the correct JSON code, except for a further instruction.

I think it is a mistake for jQuery not be able to change the codes indicating a request as having failed. The content of the response may be important anyway and require special processing.
For a complete web page, the browser still displays the content returned by the server in case of error.

Comment: I don't think coercing jQuery into doing that (e.g. through `$.ajaxTransport()`) is the right direction to take. Instead, you could add an `error` callback, check if the result was `401`, and act accordingly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, given the need for that to go through the "complete" method, it is necessary to recode the entire automation of jQuery.
So there is no interest in using $ .ajax in this case.

That's why I had to code this replacement function that uses the jQuery syntax:

```
var altAjax = function(opts){
    var options = {
        url: '',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'text',
        successCodes: [304, 401, 403, 404, 500],
        statusCode: {},
        success: [],
        error: [],
        complete: []
    };
    $.extend(options, opts);

    var success = function(data, textStatus, xhr){
        if ($.isArray(options.success)){
            $.each(options.success, function(index, callback){
                callback(data, textStatus, xhr);
            });
        } else if ($.isFunction(options.success)){
            options.success(data, textStatus, xhr);
        }
        if ($.isFunction(options.statusCode[xhr.status])){
            options.statusCode[xhr.status](data, textStatus, xhr);
        }
    }

    var error = function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        if ($.isArray(options.error)){
            $.each(options.error, function(index, callback){
                callback(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
            });
        } else if ($.isFunction(options.error)){
            options.error(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
        if ($.isFunction(options.statusCode[xhr.status])){
            options.statusCode[xhr.status](xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    }

    var complete = function(xhr, textStatus){
        if ($.isArray(options.complete)){
            $.each(options.complete, function(index, callback){
                callback(xhr, textStatus);
            });
        } else if ($.isFunction(options.complete)){
            options.complete(xhr, textStatus);
        }
    }

    var dataString = '';
    $.each(options.data, function(key, value){
        dataString += ((dataString.length > 0) ? '&' : '') + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(($.isArray(value) || $.isPlainObject(value)) ? JSON.stringify(value) : value);
    });

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = options.url;
    if (options.type.toUpperCase() != 'POST'){
        url += ((url.indexOf('?') > -1) ? '&' : '?') + dataString;
    }
    req.onload = function(){
        var textStatus = 'error';
        if ((this.status >= 200 && this.status <= 299) || $.inArray(this.status, options.successCodes) > -1) {
            var data;
            switch (options.dataType.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'json':
                    try {
                        data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    } catch (ex){
                        error(this, textStatus, ex.name + ': ' + ex.message);
                        break;
                    }
                    textStatus = 'success';
                    success(data, textStatus, this);
                    break;
                case 'xml':
                    try {
                        data = $.parseXML(this.responseText);
                    } catch (ex){
                        error(this, textStatus, ex.name + ': ' + ex.message);
                        break;
                    }
                    textStatus = 'success';
                    success(data, textStatus);
                    break;
                default:
                    textStatus = 'success';
                    success(this.responseText, textStatus);
            }
        } else {
            error(this, textStatus, null);
        }
        complete(this, textStatus);
    };
    req.open(options.type, url, true);
    if (options.type.toUpperCase() == 'POST'){
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.send(dataString);
    } else {
        req.send();
    }
    req = null;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to override the "success" callback why not just make the function call inside the "error" callback,ofcourse before checking the specific error occurred.

```
error: function(a, b, c){
  if(a.status == 401){
    // Your custom function call / code.

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to handle the status code in the `success` or `error` block? How about the `complete` block? It follows both outcomes..

> complete
>
> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )
>
> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "nocontent", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). As of jQuery 1.5, the complete setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.google.com"
}).success(function(){  //--> use .done() instead
    //things to do on success

}).error(function(){ //--> use .fail() instead
    //things to do on error

}).complete(function( data ) { //--> use .always() instead
    switch(data.status){
        //your logic here
    }
});
```

Comment: I edited my question to show my current code.

PS: You should not use the .success() method but instead the .done() method or the success option.

Comment: Also you should use `.always()` instead `.complete()` View the **[`.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR)** notes. `jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) { });`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of success use the `complete` function and check the `xhr.statusText` value

```
$.ajax('url.json', {
  complete:function(result) {
    if(/^(2\d\d|304|401)$/.test(result.statusText)) {
      success();
    } else {
      error();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I had thought to that solution, and besides I already manage specific HTTP codes with the "statusCode" option. The problem is that in this case, I don't benefit anymore of the evaluation of JSON.
How to use the property "dataType" (JSON or XML) working?

Answer (score -2):

You need to handle the conditions at client side checking the status code. You can fetch the status as below:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  console.log(xhr.status);
},
```